# How to serialize single row in DataTables.net?

Tags: javascript

I have a DataTables.net's table with inputs fields.

```
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
      <thead>
          <tr class="text-center">
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Level</th>
            <th scope="col">Save</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for member in form.users %}
          <tr>
              <td>{{ member.username(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}</td>
              <td>{{ member.user_level(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}</td>
              <td><button type="button" user_id="{{member.id}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-save-user">Save</button></td>
          </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

So i edit values and now want to save row by pressing row's `Save` button:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-save-user', function (e) {
        var row = dataTable.row( dataTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).index( ));
        console.log(row.node().$('input, select').serialize());
      });
```

But get an error:

```
row.node(...).$ is not a function
```

If i do:

```
console.log(row.nodes().$('input, select').serialize());
```

I get values of all rows.

How to get values from imputs of one single row?

Comment: try using `.find()` on the jQuery object returned by .to$()` (which is the same as `.tojQuery()` like this: `.nodes().to$().find('input, select')` which gives you both reference https://datatables.net/reference/api/to%24()

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Thank you, this it exactly what i looking for. Can you write answer? And i will acapt it.

Comment: what is the data structure of `console.log(row.nodes().$('input, select').serialize());`
if it is an array, well work with it like that like `console.log(row.nodes().$('input, select').serialize())[index];` or if an object, Object.keys(console.log(row.nodes().$('input, select').serialize()))[index];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `.find()` on the jQuery object returned by `.to$()` (which is the same as `.tojQuery()` like this: `.nodes().to$().find('input, select')` which gives you both reference https://datatables.net/reference/api/to%24()